# How to access permanently removed pages using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am facing a problem in using SPARQL with DBPedia.

for example if I call this link directly

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Venice,_Italy
```

I see a 301 redirect code to

```
http://dbpedia.org/page/Venice
```

but if i try to call `Venice,_Italy` resorce using SPARQL I get nothing back.

```
define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org> 
PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>  
PREFIX property: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
PREFIX resource: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX position:<http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?Abstract ?ThumbnailURL WHERE 
{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Venice,_Italy>  ontology:abstract  ?Abstract.  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Venice,_Italy> ontology:thumbnail ?ThumbnailURL.
 FILTER (lang(?Abstract)="en")}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the `ontology:wikiPageRedirects` property to ensure your query actually gets an answer by traversing the redirect in your query e.g.

```
PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>  
PREFIX property: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
PREFIX resource: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX position:<http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?Abstract ?ThumbnailURL
 WHERE 
{ 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Venice,_Italy> ontology:wikiPageRedirects ?page .
  ?page  ontology:abstract  ?Abstract. 
  ?page ontology:thumbnail ?ThumbnailURL.
  FILTER (lang(?Abstract)="en")
}
```